# Is inline and override possible in F#? What are the alternatives?

Tags: generics, f#

Suppose I have a generic record struct like this:

```ml
[<Struct>]
type Container<'t when 't : (member ToString : Unit -> string) > =
  {
    Item : 't
  }
  with
    member inline this.ToString () =
      sprintf "(%s)" (this.Item.ToString ())
```

This gives a compilation warning:

> This new member hides the abstract member 'System.Object.ToString() : string'. Rename the member or use 'override' instead.

But if I switch to `override` I get an error:

```ml
[<Struct>]
type Container<'t when 't : (member ToString : Unit -> string) > =
  {
    Item : 't
  }
  with
    override inline this.ToString () =
      sprintf "(%s)" (this.Item.ToString ())
```

> This member, function or value declaration may not be declared 'inline'

If I remove the `inline` then I get a new error:

```ml
[<Struct>]
type Container<'t when 't : (member ToString : Unit -> string) > =
  {
    Item : 't
  }
  with
    member this.ToString () =
      sprintf "(%s)" (this.Item.ToString ())
```

> This code is not sufficiently generic. The type variable  ^t when  ^t : (member ToString :  ^t -> string) could not be generalized because it would escape its scope.

How should I implement this in F#?

Comment: Live with the warning?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I suppose that I could, although I would expect this to be possible somehow without warnings

Comment: https://robkuz.github.io/Decoupling-Strategies-I/ seems to provide some insight into these errors.

Comment: Why do you need the `member ToString : Unit -> string` constraint? Every object has such method anyway.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin You're right. I was experimenting around the error, I don't think it makes a difference either way

Comment: @sdgfsdh Error goes away if you remove constraints properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have override and inline on the same member, since override requires the method "to exist" to override the base class in the CLR.

That being said, you can simplify this by using `%O`:

```
[<Struct>]
type Container<'t> =
  {
    Item : 't
  }
  with
    override this.ToString () =
      sprintf "(%O)" this.Item
```

That being said, if you remove the constraints, this works with %s and ToString as well:

```
[<Struct>]
type Container<'t> =
  {
    Item : 't
  }
  with
    override this.ToString () =
      sprintf "(%s)" (this.Item.ToString ())
```

Comment: Why does this work? Isn't the constraint of having `ToString` always met?

Comment: @sdgfsdh Generic method constraints are statically resolved, and only work with inline. You can't have the inline, so you get an error. It always works (as you saw) without a constraint, so you can leave it out.